# Calcular diferença entre datas

Tags: java, android, data

Preciso calcular a diferença entre a data de cadastro e a data atual, caso seja maior do que 6 meses, retornar booleano. Eu estou cadastrando no banco a data de cadastro da seguinte forma:

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "dd/MM/yyyy";

public static String date() 
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
        return sdf.format(cal.getTime());

    }
```

E jogo esta função date para o banco, agora preciso fazer a diferença entre ela e o atual.

Comment: Aonde você quer fazer isso? Em uma query? Ou você deseja calcular isto nos resultados de uma query, manipulando diretamente em Java? O que você tentou?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a biblioteca Joda-time e facilite a sua vida: [Link](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time)

Essa biblioteca facilita muitas coisas ao se lidar com datas, e deve ser a melhor para trabalhar com isso em java. Para fazer o que você quer você pode tentar isso:

```
Period period = new Period(data1, data2);
period.getMonths(); // vai retornar a diferença de meses entre as duas datas
```

Answer (score 16):

Com o Java 8 não é necessário usar uma biblioteca externa para calcular a diferença entre duas datas de forma confiável. Além disso, é recomendável não usar a classe `java.util.Date` em muitos casos.

Para calcular a diferença entre meses de forma simples, basta fazer algo assim:

```
//define datas
LocalDateTime dataCadastro = LocalDateTime.of(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
LocalDateTime hoje = LocalDateTime.now();

//calcula diferença
long meses = dataCadastro.until(hoje, ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
```

Vale notar que a diferença será apenas no número de meses, sem considerar o dia. Se o cadastro foi feito no dia 31 de um determinado mês, no dia seguinte a rotina apontará 1 mês de diferença. Então é importante descrever no sistema uma regra de negócio definindo exatamente o que consiste uma *diferença de **n** meses*.

Se você não possui Java 8, também não precisa de uma biblioteca para fazer essa diferença simples. Pode usar a classe `java.util.Calendar`:

```
//define datas
Calendar dataCadastro = Calendar.getInstance();
dataCadastro.set(2015, 1, 1);
Calendar hoje = Calendar.getInstance();

//calcula diferença
int meses = (hoje.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 12 + hoje.get(Calendar.MONTH))
        - (dataCadastro.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 12 + dataCadastro.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

O método acima usa uma técnica simples que calcula o número de meses que as datas contém, multiplicando o ano por 12 e somando os meses, depois faz a subtração simples. Esta é uma técnica muito comum e funciona bem quando o objetivo é desconsiderar dias e horas, sendo que a utilizei com frequência em sistemas contábeis.

Por fim, se precisar transformar um `Date` em `Calendar`, basta fazer:

```
calendar.setTime(date);
```

Comment: Muito boa resposta @utluiz, eu não sabia disso, quanto ao java 8, obrigado! O bom do Joda-Time, é todo o montante de funcionalidades extras que ele traz de bônus e de um jeito fácil de se fazer. Mas se ele precisa de algo específico somente, isso aí seria uma solução.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Data(28,2,2000,1,3,2008);

}

public static void Data (int dia1,int mes1,int ano1,int dia2,int mes2,int ano2){    

    int mes []= {31,0,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};       
    int dias = 0, meses = 0, anos = 0;  
    String temp = Integer.toString(ano1);

    if(temp.charAt(temp.length() - 1) == '0' && temp.charAt(temp.length() - 2) == '0') {             
        if(ano1 % 400 == 0) {
            mes[1] = 29;
        }else {
            mes[1] = 28;
        }       
    }else if(ano1 % 4 == 0) {
        mes[1] = 29;
    }else {
        mes[1] = 28;
    }       

    anos = ano2 - ano1;

    if(mes2 > mes1 || mes1 == mes2) {
        meses = mes2 - mes1;
    }else {
        meses = 12 - (mes1 - mes2);
        anos -= 1;
    }

    if(dia2 > dia1 || dia1 == dia2) {
        dias = dia2 - dia1;
    }else {
        dias = (mes[mes1 - 1] - dia1) + dia2;
        meses -= 1;
    }

    System.out.printf("* Diferença em dias/meses/anos:\n\n-> %d dia(s) / %d mes(es) / %d ano(s) .\n\n",dias,meses,anos);    

}
```